# The semi artinianity of a module is preserved under module morphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

We define a **semi-artinian** $R$ module $M$ as a $R$ module such

$$\operatorname{Soc}(M/U) \neq 0$$

for every $U \leq M$ submodule. Also we define **semiartinianity** of a $M$ as $R$ module is defined as

$$\operatorname{sa}(M):= \sum \lbrace M' \leq M \mid M' \: \mbox{is semi-artinian} \rbrace$$

What I want to prove is that for every $R$-module morphism $f:M \to N$ we have that $f(\operatorname{sa}(M)) \leq \operatorname{sa}(N)$. My idea is to  visualize first that $f(M)$ is semiartinian if $M$ is semiartinian. Let suppose $M$ is semiartinian so $Soc(M/M') \neq 0$ for every $M' \leq M$ but $f(M)$ is not semiartinian this means $Soc(f(M)/N')=0$ for some $N' \leq f(M)$. So lets take preimage of $f^{-1}(N') \leq M$ so $Soc(M/f^{-1}(N'))\neq 0$ as $M$ is semiartinian. This way for $f \neq 0$ we have that $0 \neq f(Soc(M/f^{-1}(N'))) \leq Soc(f(M)/N')=0 $ by properties of socle which is a contradiction.

Comment: I found a useful characterization of $\mathrm{sa}(M)$ as "the union of the socle series of $M$."  Maybe a good way is to try to show that the images of socle series in $M$ lie in the socle series of $N$?

Comment: Where did you find that characterization? I found in some articles that semiartinian is also called Loewy modules. This is an exercise by Kasch module and ring theory so thought this could be solved more directly. Also I already edit my attempt to prove this, let me know what you think about it. @rschwieb

Comment: > Dung, Nguyen Viet. Extending modules. Routledge, 2019.
Halfway down page 27,

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you make me doubt the inequality in the last line now @rschwieb